# How can I prevent water from puddling in a play area?

Tags: drainage

We have clay in our yard. I have spent a good two hours digging out the square space under our slide area of our swing set. I dug deep enough to have deep enough sand for the kids. However, due to the clay bottom I'm concerned in getting standing water inside after rain or when using the hose. What can I do to ensure drainage? Any suggestions? I'm ready to put weed fabric down then sand. Our swing sets sits on a bank so there is a slope behind the set itself.

Thank you.

Comment: I fixed your many typos. Please edit to describe your yard a bit or add photos. Drainage involves gravity, and we need to know what options are available.

Comment: Probably no need to over-design it.  Even clay will drain.  You would need a ridiculously complicated drainage system unless this is on or near a hill.  Just let nature dry things out and the kids can play video games in the mean time.  :-)  An alternate solution: raise the swing set and have a raised sand pit inside framing.  Water can easy drain from that, both into the ground below and through drainage holes in the sides

Comment: You said the swing set is close to a slope. Is it sloping downward away from the set or toward the set / is the set the bottom or top of the slope?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the fabric in and see how it works. If the hole holds water then dig a trench from the low side of the area to your sand box area. I would normally use perf pipe but you may be able to put some sand / gravel in the cloth and drop it in the trench and cover up. The water would drain through the sand. And water the lower area.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put it a simple french drain by making a post hole under the sand area.